# Is there an idiomatic way to find min/max of transform of array without storing the transform or needlessly recalculating?

Tags: c++, performance, min

I have an array of some data type `T` on which I have to perform some `long_calculation(const T&)` and find its minimum value. Because the array is pretty large and the function takes a significant amount of my run-time, I want to do it in a multi-threaded way and in the most efficient way possible. The closest thing to what I'm looking for seems to be `std::min_element` but it is not a perfect fit because it doesn't seem to work internally with the values it calculates and it doesn't even return the value I want. This forces me to do something like the following.

```
const auto iter = std::min_element(std::execution::par_unseq,
    my_container.begin(), my_container.end(), [](const T& t1, const T& t2) {
        return long_calculation(t1) < long_calculation(t2);
    }
const auto value = long_calculation(*T1);
```

The standard guarantees at most N-1 comparisons but without storing the result of `long_calculation` I expect 2N-2 calculations rather than the optimal N. Or rather 2N-1 because of the final line.

On the other hand, pre-calculating the values and doing the search does N `long_calculation`s but uses `O(N)` extra storage which will also have to be dynamically allocated in my case.

Is there any way to do this in a generic fashion in the standard or some 3rd party library? If not, what is the most appropriate way to do this? The ideal solution would be a multi-threaded function that can be called somewhat like this.

```
const auto min_value = min_of_transform(
    my_container.begin(), my_container.end(), long_calculation);
```

Comment: You can't compute the transformed values in parallel without storing them. With maximum parallelism you can find the max in log(n) steps, just bubbling it up through a binary tree, since then you have one task per item. Not sure how to fit that to the standard library's functionality, though.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It seems that I could get away with storing only as many values as I have threads and then doing an extra search for `min` on those. Because the number of threads is expected to be low, this is negligible storage requirement..

Comment: Hm, I can't even use the coffee excuse this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `std::transform_reduce` algorithm:

```
std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, my_container.begin(), my_container.end(),
                      std::numeric_limits<T>::max(),
                      [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { return std::min(x, y); },
                      long_calculation);
```